# Localhost not connecting to Sepolia network

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I wrote a Dapp and trying to connect to coinbase wallet on sepolia network. The wallet shows connected but console throws the following error :
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvVUb.png)
Code:

```
 window.ethereum.enable(); // this enables the browser to detect any present wallet or ether source
    var provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(
        web3.currentProvider,
        'sepolia'
    );
```

I am trying to remove this error so that the html is connected over sepolia

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem when trying to connect my first dApp to Sepolia network and was able to resolve by changing the ethers version to 5.7.2.  Note that I also had an error with 6.2.3 and I chose 5.7.2 simply because it was the most recent version with significant number of downloads on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethers?activeTab=versions)

```
<script
    src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.7.2.umd.min.js"
    type="application/javascript">
</script>
```

Comment: This solution worked for me as well. https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.7.2.umd.min.js
Thank you for sharing.